# Read last csv file from s3 bucket using Pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark

So I have an s3 bucket(data) in which I have a folder named(first) which contains multiple CSV files and I don't know the names of that file now I want to read the most recent file from that folder into pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For downloading the CSVs from S3 you will have to download them one by one:

```
import os
import boto3

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)

def aws_session(region_name='us-east-1'):
    return boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                            aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET'),
                            region_name=region_name)


def download_file_from_bucket(bucket_name, s3_key, dst_path):
    session = aws_session()
    s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.download_file(Key=s3_key, Filename=dst_path)

download_file_from_bucket('tci-s3-demo', 'children.csv', 'children_download.csv')
```

The upper code will help you download a file from a S3 Bucket on any destination path.

The below code should be modified accordingly to upload schema from a CSV file in spark

```
df = spark.read.csv("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")
df.printSchema()
```